# GitHub repository archived: How can I register my Solana Token?

Tags: json, solana

I've recently created my Solana Token, and while attempting to register my token I found out the GitHub repository has been archived. So how should I go about registering my newly created Solana Token?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How create token at solana with image , and dissabled mint new tokens now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175019/how-create-token-at-solana-with-image-and-dissabled-mint-new-tokens-now)

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub repository gives full instructions detailing the new procedure on-chain token metadata: https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list#read-below-for-instructions-on-new-token-metadata-flow

Quoting directly from the repo:

> You can use one of two tools at the time of writing:
>
> ```
> Strata Protocol Token Launchpad
> Token Creator Demo
> ```
>
> All new token metadata will be added using Metaplex Fungible Token
> Metadata. The steps to add new Fungible Token Metadata are as follows:
>
> ```
> Use CreateMetadataV2 instruction from Metaplex token metadata to create new metadata for token.
> Make sure you use the correct format for the token metadata.
> You must have mint authority in order to create or update the metadata
> ```